# Can't get my constness right

Tags: c++

I have a Node class defined like this (this is a minimal version):

```
class Node {
    private:
        std::vector <const Node*> leaves;

     public:
        Node* getLeaf(int i);
}
```

In other words, I want getLeaf to return a pointer to an element of the vector "leaves"

I tried defining getLeaf like so

```
Node* Node::getLeaf(int i){
    return leaves[i];
}
```

Ok, so I know I'm screwing the constness up. I've tried variations of const modifiers in my function declarations / definitions to no luck. Someone please help :)

Comment: check your return type for constness.

Comment: You either want to return `const Node*`, or hold non-const `Node*` in the vector. Returning a non-const pointer to a const object would screw up constness, as you say (unless you to something evil and probably buggy with `const_cast`).

Comment: You just need to set the return type to: `const Node* Node::getLeaf(int i)`

Comment: I still get the same error.. is that the correct placement for const?

Answer (score 0):

`const` is a promise to not change.

You declare a vector of pointers to `const` nodes. That's a promise to not change any `Node` via these pointers.

The `getLeaf` function can't very well then return a pointer to non-`const` node, because then the caller can do anything with the node.

So you have to make either the same promise both places, or don't make any such promise.

---

Another matter is whether `getLeaf` itself should be `const` (it probably should, it makes sense to let it promise not to change the object), and a second other matter is whether `get` makes sense as a prefix in C++ (usually not, it's just needless verbosity, while in Java there are tools that can make good use of such of prefix), I'd just call it `node`.

Comment: For some reason, I have to declare the vector as const. Otherwise, I get the error "leaves is private"

Comment: hm, those issues, constness and access, don't have anything to do with each other. or as we often say, they're orthogonal.